# How to make host interfaces, including cni* accessible in kubernetes privileged pods?

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, flannel

We would like see traffic from other interfaces on the host, but noticed that they are not visible in the kubernetes pods. Is there an option that can be configured in the yaml file to make the interface(s) visible in the pods which are running in privileged mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `hostNetwork: true` your Pod will see the host interfaces.

Technically you only need CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW to use promiscuous mode. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/container-capabilities/ for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The hostNetwork addresses our needs.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful :)

Comment: Note that the ability to place a CNI plugin into promiscuous mode is up for review here https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/pull/441.